# leanModal popup not appearing on trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hav used leanModal.min.js for my popup but for some reason its not working.I am doubting that there might a problem related to z-index or jquery library version I am using. Please help....

css

```
<style>
#lean_overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}
#mod{
display:none;   
z-index:10000;
width:330px;
    height: auto;
    left:45%;
    top:80px;
    background: #FFF;
}
</style>
```

html

```
<div id="mod"><p>Hello</p></div>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });

});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var jQuery_1_11_1 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var jQuery_1_6_1 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Comment: Check for any `console errors`

Comment: no errors related to this in console

Comment: Ok then, could you please add a demo?

Comment: Browser Console showing this

Comment: index.php:1033 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery_1_6_1(...).leanModal is not a function(anonymous function) @ index.php:1033resolveWith @ jquery.min.js:16ready @ jquery.min.js:16z @ jquery.min.js:16

Comment: Try removing reference to `1.6` version.. Just keep `1.11` and check if you are getting this error?

Comment: the error is gone but popup still not appeared

Comment: Please add a `DEMO` if possible..